# node.js https/www redirect to https non-www on nginx

Tags: nginx, redirect, node.js

I'm using nginx for my node.js app.
I've used the [Digitalocean tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-16-04#set-up-nginx-as-a-reverse-proxy-server) to config the nginx and https use. 
Right now, the following works:
http:// example.com -> https:// example.com
example.com  --> https:// example.com
www.example.com --> https:// example.com
http:// www.example.com --> https:// example.com

but when i enter https:// www.example.com, it does not redirect to https:// example.com

here is my nginx congif on sites-available/default

```
# HTTP - redirect all requests to HTTPS:
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

# HTTPS - proxy requests on to local Node.js app:
server {
        listen 443;
        server_name ezplan.ir;

        ssl on;
        # Use certificate and key provided by Let's Encrypt:
        ssl_certificate /path/to.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /path/to.key;
        ssl_session_timeout 5m;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_ciphers 'SSL STUFF';

        # Pass requests for / to localhost:8080:
        location / {
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
                proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                proxy_redirect off;
        }
}
```

can anyone help me do this redirection as well?

Comment: You should use `return 301 https://example.com$request_uri` in your first server block, so that a request to `http://www.example.com` would go directly to `https://example.com`, without going to `https://www.example.com` first. Otherwise rsp's answer below fixes the main issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can do two blocks for https - with and without www:

```
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name www.example.com;
    // ...
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443;
    server_name example.com;
    // ...
    // your normal config here - proxy to node and all that
}
```